# Free memory from data structure

Tags: c, memory, struct, malloc, free

I have a data structure that contains a size and some data. I want to free the memory when I allocate it.

My struct:

```
struct test_t {
    int size; 
    void *data;   
};
```

In order to create my structure I alloc `test->data` and then alloc `struct test_t`. Like shown:

```
struct teest_t *data_create(int size, void *data){
  if (size <= 0 || data == NULL) return NULL;

  struct test_t *new_data = malloc( sizeof(struct test_t));

  new_data->size = size;

  new_data->data = malloc(sizeof(*data));
  new_data->data = data;

  return new_data;
}
```

Now when I want to free my memory it causes a `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`. This is my function:

```
void data_destroy(struct test_t *data){

  if (data->data == NULL) free(data->data);
  free(data);
}
```

Comment: Och, it's gcc [extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.2/gcc/Pointer-Arith.html#Pointer-Arith). I would expect `sizeof(void)` to be invalid.

Comment: What is this code supposed to do? Shouldn't data be a `void **` pointer?

Comment: @KamilCuk The void* is so that the struct can receive any kind of data pointer

Comment: Why are trying to free something you know to be null?

Comment: But what is the size of that kind of data? If it is `int size` obtained using `sizeof` (which returns `size_t` not `int`...), then you should allocate memory using `malloc(size)`. Why are using `sizeof` there, it's `sizeof(void)`.

Answer (score 4):

It is wrong of course. Is you save the reference to the data the second malloc is not needed at all.

If you want to save the data itself you need to allocate the buffer of the size of the `data` and then copy the `data` to the allocated buff.

The version you have now only leaks the memory. You do not have to allocate memory for the pointer, only for the actually data

Answer (score 1):

```
new_data->data = malloc(sizeof(*data));
new_data->data = data;
```

You first allocate memory, then loose the pointer (memory leak) and overwrite the pointer value with data pointer value. The second line copies pointer value, not bytes behind pointers. For that use `memcpy`.

You probably want:

```
new_data->data = malloc(size);
memcpy(new_data->data, data, size);
```

This will allocate new memory block `size` bytes big and copy the `size` bytes of data pointed to by `data` pointer.

Example:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <string.h>

struct test_t {
    size_t size; 
    void *data;   
};

struct test_t *data_create(size_t size, void *data){
  if (size <= 0 || data == NULL) return NULL;

  struct test_t *new_data = malloc(sizeof(struct test_t));
  if (new_data == NULL) {
     goto NEW_DATA_MALLOC_ERR;
  }

  new_data->size = size;
  new_data->data = malloc(size);
  if (new_data->data == NULL) {
      goto NEW_DATA_DATA_MALLOC_ERR;
  }
  memcpy(new_data->data, data, size);

  return new_data;

NEW_DATA_DATA_MALLOC_ERR:
  free(new_data);
NEW_DATA_MALLOC_ERR:
  return NULL;
}

void data_destroy(struct test_t *data) {

  if (data->data == NULL) {
      free(data->data);
  }
  free(data);
}

int main() {
    int object = 1;
    struct test_s *A = data_create(sizeof(object), &object);
    data_destroy(A);
}
```